# Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install'- Conflict in linux-image

Tags: apt, 20.04, kernel, xubuntu, dpkg

I can't install packages with `apt`. I am using Ubuntu 20.04 Focal.

Some packages require `linux-image-5.11.0-38-generic`, as seen below.

```json
:~$ sudo apt install <package>

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04 : Depends: linux-image-5.11.0-38-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-modules-5.11.0-38-generic : Depends: linux-image-5.11.0-38-generic but it is not going to be installed or
                                            linux-image-unsigned-5.11.0-38-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-modules-extra-5.11.0-38-generic : Depends: linux-image-5.11.0-38-generic but it is not going to be installed or
                                                  linux-image-unsigned-5.11.0-38-generic but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

My kernel:

```
$ uname -r
5.11.0-37-generic
```

Can I install 5.11.0-38 somehow? Or downgrade these packages so that they will be compatible with 5.11.0-37?

**Edit**
The answers are correct and working. I had to turn off my antivirus first in order for them to work.

Comment: You have at least "53 packages not upgraded" which suggests that you have deferred maintenance. Can you run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`?  These commands should always be run before installing any new software.

Comment: @Nmath
Already tried these. I can update normally,but when i try to upgrade the errors from 1. show up (see my question for "1." - E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install')
Thanks for your time

Comment: When was the last time you were able to successfully complete this system maintenance and what changes have been made to the system since then?

Comment: See the edited part of my questions

Comment: Do you happen to run Sophos antivirus or some other antivirus service in the system?

Comment: @jarno
My company runs mcaffe antivirus on all laptops

Comment: https://kc.mcafee.com/corporate/index?page=content&id=KB87210&locale=en_US

Comment: Edited the question.I hope it is more helpful now. I realized me kernel is linux-image-5.11.0-37-generic and the 5.11.0-38 is not installed

Comment: I think your antivirus software may prevent installing a new kernel.  Maybe the link I gave above helps.

Comment: jarno You were correct. I disabled mcaffe and run 'sudo apt --fix-broken install' and the problem was solved. Big thanks to @Algnis for helping me

Comment: @Ermolai I am happy to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution (specific for your issue)

```
 sudo rm -rf /var/cache/apt/archives/linux*
```

This command removes every file which was causing errors

If this didn't worked

Then

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-modules-5.11.0-38-generic 
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-modules-extra-5.11.0-38-generic
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-generic-hwe-20.04
sudo apt install linux-modules-5.11.0-38-generic linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04  linux-modules-extra-5.11.0-38-generic linux-generic-hwe-20.04
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Also you should disable your antivirus and then run 'sudo apt --fix-broken install`.

Comment: Didn't work :( 
Thanks for your time :)

Comment: @Ermolai see the edited thing

Comment: I removed the files you specified. When i tried to run "apt install... " 
https://i.imgur.com/oX4EYMG.png

Comment: Can you run other commands like `sudo apt upgrade` @Ermolai

Comment: No the same error keeps poping-up. https://i.imgur.com/2n1Ghky.png
Is the only solution to just re-install ubuntu?

Comment: 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' https://i.imgur.com/Nwzsijn.png

Comment: @Ermolai is aptitude installed ? `sudo aptitude -f install`

Comment: No it is not https://i.imgur.com/TUXvaHm.png

Comment: Also:
```
`sudo dpkg --remove linux-image-5.11.0-38-generic`
`\n `
`dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove linux-image-5.11.0-38-generic which isn't installed`

Comment: Also edited the question.I hope it is more helpful now. I realized me kernel is `linux-image-5.11.0-37-generic` and the 5.11.0-38 is not installed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131276/discussion-between-algnis-and-ermolai).

Comment: I thought this was something to do with McAfee? Can you edit your answer to contain what actually worked, if so?

Comment: The comments suggest it didn’t work but the answer is accepted & upvoted - did it work in the end?

Comment: @Will It is a long story , You need to see [This chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131276/discussion-between-algnis-and-ermolai) to know what happened

Comment: You know, sometimes this happens when a kernel is released and all the dependencies aren't released yet. On packages.ubuntu.com these dependencies will show up as suggested packages and will say "not available". So you can probably force the install using `sudo apt install --no-install-recommends linux-image-5.11.0-38-generic`.

Answer (score 6):

From this [tutorial](https://itsfoss.com/dpkg-returned-an-error-code-1/):

### Method 1: Reconfigure Package Database

The first method you can try is to reconfigure the package database. Probably the database got corrupted while installing a package. Reconfiguring often fixes the problem.

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

### Method 2: Use fix broken

If a package installation was interrupted previously, you may use the `install -f` options to automatically attempt to correct a system with broken dependencies in place.

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

### Method 3: Try removing the troublesome package

If it’s not an issue for you, you may try to remove the package manually. Please don’t do it for Linux Kernels (packages starting with linux-).

```
sudo apt remove package_name
```

### Method 4: Remove post info files of the troublesome package

This should be your last resort. You can try removing the files associated to the package in question from /var/lib/dpkg/info.

Answer (score 1):

So I found the answer in my case was a bad /etc/default/grub file. I found an extra pair of quotes on my GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT= that i had edited a while back.

I fixed the grub file and ran update-grub rebooted, then did an apt --fix-broken install. This fixed my updates and now I'm on 5.11.0-41-generic with no issues.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes this happens when a kernel is released and all the dependencies aren't released or available yet. On packages.ubuntu.com the unmet dependencies for `linux-image-5.11.0-38-generic` (or whatever the specific kernel version is) will show up as suggested packages and will say "not available".

If you try to do `apt-cache show <packagename>` for one of the dependencies that are listed as "not available" yet, it will complain that the package is strictly a virtual package or must be provided by some other package. This of course, is not entirely true as the package is simply not available yet but apt assumes otherwise.

So you have at least two possible options.

1. You can probably force the install using `sudo apt install --no-install-recommends linux-image-5.11.0-38-generic`. But this will leave you without the modules, tools, and header packages which may cause issues.
2. Simply wait a few hours or maybe a full day and the problem will go away on its own when the dependencies are released. A simple `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt full-upgrade` will install all available packages.

---

I recently had the same problem with a subsequent hwe kernel update on 20.04. Apt said there were 4 updates available but when I ran `sudo apt dist-upgrade` or `full-upgrade` it would say 0 packages installed.

Checking the output of `apt list --upgradable` revealed hwe kernel updates but manually installing `linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04` and the other packages gave the same errors shown in the question but different versions, of course.