# cannot use `sudo apt install` any packages - sudo apt --fix broken install error

Tags: 20.04

I cannot use `sudo apt install` any packages
I have tried `sudo apt --fix broken install`

however it keep hitting dependencies error.

```
$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  linux-image-5.11.0-41-generic
Suggested packages:
  fdutils linux-doc | linux-hwe-5.11-source-5.11.0 linux-hwe-5.11-tools
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-image-5.11.0-41-generic
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 14 not upgraded.
7 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/11.5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 11.8 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 259233 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-5.11.0-41-generic_5.11.0-41.45~20.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-5.11.0-41-generic (5.11.0-41.45~20.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-5.11.0-41-generic_5.11.0-41.45~20.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to open '/boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-41-generic.dpkg-new': Operation not permitted
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-5.11.0-41-generic_5.11.0-41.45~20.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 1):

##### You can easily fix this issue!

You need to force overwrite the files, probably the last time you ran `apt upgrade`, a kernel upgrade was there. It seems like you are probably using an antivirus, if yes then diable it and proceed, and if no then proceed

So after making sure your antivirus services are disabled run -

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-5.11.0-41-generic_5.11.0-41.45~20.04.1_amd64.deb
```

Now the problem should be gone

##### Meaning of what we did

Normally, some antivirus services doesn't let tools like Dpkg to acess `/boot` directory in order to provide security but when there is a kernel upgrade Dpkg is forced to access the `/boot` directory, without it, it cannot install kernel, the antivirus wasn't allowing Dpkg to use `/boot` so disabling antivirus will allow Dpkg to use `/boot`

After that, we ran a command, that command does nothing but allow Dpkg to forceoverwrite the directory in which the package (kernel) `linux-image-5.11.0-41-generic_5.11.0-41.45~20.04.1_amd64.deb` was installed, So that Dpkg can reinstall it.

##### Confirming everything

First of all run 
`sudo apt --fix-broken install` 
 to confirm the fix.

Then make sure the kernel is installed by 
`sudo apt-get upgrade`

Now after this is done you may want to clean the computer by running 
`sudo apt clean && sudo apt autoremove`

##### I hope so, I helped

Comment: I tried to force overwrite. error dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-5.11.0-41-generic_5.11.0-41.45~20.04.1_amd64.deb (--install):
 unable to open '/boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-41-generic.dpkg-new': Operation not permitted
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-5.11.0-41-generic_5.11.0-41.45~20.04.1_amd64.deb

Comment: i am using corp laptop. no antivirus, or does it means the IT blocks something?

Comment: @guo yeah, I think so there must be some issue with any kind of blocking service, I would recommend running `sudo rm -rf /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb`

Comment: Also, please run `sudo apt upgrade` afterwards @guo

Comment: @guo are you sure you are not using any antivirus service? There must be something as it simply says cannot open /boot

Comment: Look at this answer - https://askubuntu.com/a/1374271/1460940 by me the person is facing the same issue as you but it is because of unmet dependencies instead of /var problem but he also has the same issue and was fixed by disabling antivirus.

Comment: IDK what is a corp laptop, can you please elaborate @guo and again make sure you have nothing even similar to antivirus! The error message clearly says that it is due to an antivirus that is not allowing dpkg to access /boot

Comment: corporate laptop. maybe that is IT policies blocking it. anyway i will raise to IT. thanks!

Comment: found another thread i uninstall all mcafee , all working now      sudo dpkg --purge mfedx
sudo dpkg --purge mcafeetp
sudo dpkg --purge mcafeeespaac
sudo dpkg --purge mcafeeespfileaccess
sudo dpkg --purge mcafeeesp
sudo dpkg --purge mcafeert
sudo dpkg --purge mfecma
sudo dpkg --purge mfert

Comment: @guo Can you post a detailed answer

Answer (score 1):

The blocking is due to antivirus program. Removed them:

```
sudo dpkg --purge mfedx 
sudo dpkg --purge mcafeetp 
sudo dpkg --purge mcafeeespaac 
sudo dpkg --purge mcafeeespfileaccess 
Sudo dpkg --purge mcafeeesp 
sudo dpkg --purge mcafeert 
sudo dpkg --purge mfecma 
sudo dpkg --purge mfert
```